# set operation for union and intersection

Tags: analysis

How to write this in math notation
$$A=\{2,4,...,2n,...\}
\\B=\{3,6,9,...,3n,...\}$$
what is $A\cup B$ and $A\setminus B$

by inspection, I can see that $A\cup B=\{2,3,4,6,8,9...\}=\{2,4,6...3,6,9...\}$ that is even set or multiple of 3 but I do not know how to write this in math notation
$ A\setminus B=\{2,4,8,10...\}$ ( element in A but not in B)

Can someone please help me to write this in proper way to use math notation of set.

Comment: $A\cup B=\{ m | 2 \, \mbox{or } \, 3 \, \mbox{ divides }\, m \}$ and $A\setminus B =\{ 2n \, | \, 3 \, \mbox{ does not divide } \, n \}$ ?

Comment: I don't know what is exact answer and it cannot use the "word" to describe it. You sure your answer is correct?

Comment: My answer is correct.

Comment: Also, I think your answer go back to the original set 2n and 3n

Comment: your answer is correct since your notation for AUB actually is the union of {2n} and {3n} so it must be correct since the question defined already

Comment: I am not getting the question then, is $n$ assumed to be a natural number? Or an integer maybe?

Comment: sorry, n is natural number

Comment: You can also use something like m such that there exist integer n such that m = 6n or 6n+2 or 6n + 3 or 6n + 4 for union case and m = 6n+2 or 6n+4 for difference case.

Comment: yes, that what I want to describe but I don't know exact the answer since I cannot figure out the general form for AUB and A\B

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what set-builder notation you use, but something like this:
$\begin{align}A & = \{k:\Bbb N^+\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N^+\;k=2n\} & = \{2,4,6,\ldots\}\\ B & = \{k:\Bbb N^+\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N^+\;k=3n\} & = \{3,6,9,\ldots\}\\ A\cap B & = \{k:\Bbb N^+\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N^+\;(k=6n)\} & = \{6,12,18\ldots\}\\ A\cup B & = \{k:\Bbb N^+\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N^+\;(k=2n\vee k=3n)\} & = \{2,3,4,6,8,9,10,\ldots\}\\ A\setminus B & = \{k:\Bbb N^+\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N^+\;(k=2n)\wedge \forall n\in\Bbb N^+\; (k\neq 3n)\} & = \{2,4,8,10,14,\ldots\}\end{align}$